# What is the term when the other person is doing same or similar thing every time you said I'm doing this or that

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, terminology

I have this person saying that when I said, I just woke up, she will then say the same thing on her reply on our exchange of messages through SMS which most often not believable at all. I know there's a term on this I just forgot.

Comment: "me-tooism"?  "copycatting"?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock +1 for me too ism

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.

Answer (score 1):

A "parrot"

In short, a "parrot" is someone who tends:

> To imitate someone or to mimic or repeat their actions or sayings without thinking.